# webpack less is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I'm using the yo fluxible generator by yahoo (following http://fluxible.io/quick-start.html).

I made a new folder called **assets** and inside it I have another folder called **styles** which will have my .less files.

So,

```
 [Project]
 |
 +-- [assets]
     |    
     +-- [styles]
         |
         +-- main.less
         |
         +-- componentOne.less
 +-- [components]
     |    
     +-- App.js
     |
     +-- ComponentOne.js
 |
 +-- webpack.config.js
```

Here's what my webpack.config.js looks like:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var webpackConfig = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './client.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.resolve('./build/js'),
        publicPath: '/public/js/',
        filename: 'main.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: [
                    require.resolve('react-hot-loader'),
                    require.resolve('babel-loader')
                ]
            },
            { test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json-loader'},
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loader: "css!less"
              }
        ]
    },
    node: {
        setImmediate: false
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env': {
                NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
            }
        })
    ],
    devtool: 'eval'
};

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

However, I get the following error when I `npm run dev`:

> module.js:340
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module './main.less'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:289:25)
>       at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
>       at require (module.js:385:17)
>       at Object. (/home/userOne/Development/reactjs/fluxible/fluxible-posts/components/Home.js:2:1)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
>       at normalLoader (/home/userOne/Development/reactjs/fluxible/fluxible-posts/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:199:5)
>       at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/home/userOne/Development/reactjs/fluxible/fluxible-posts/node_modules/babel-core/lib/api/register/node.js:216:7)
>       at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:313:12)

Here is Home.js component:

```
import React from 'react';
require('../assets/styles/main.less');

class Home extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Home</h2>
                <p>Welcome to the site!</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Home;
```

Thanks to @zerkms, I installed the less module.  However, the following now happens:

```
/home/userOne/Development/reactjs/fluxible/fluxible-posts/assets/styles/main.less: Unexpected token (1:1)
> 1 | p{color:red;}
    |  ^
    at Parser.pp.raise (/home/userOne/Development/reactjs/fluxible/fluxible-posts/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:24:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/home/userOne/Development/reactjs/fluxible/fluxible-posts/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:82:8)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (/home/userOne/Development/reactjs/fluxible/fluxible-posts/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:69:81)
    at Parser.pp.parseExpressionStatement (/home/userOne/Development/reactjs/fluxible/fluxible-posts/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/statement.js:427:8)
    at Parser.parseExpressionStatement (/home/userOne/Development/reactjs/fluxible/fluxible-posts/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/flow.js:642:20)
    at Parser.pp.parseStatement (/home/userOne/Development/reactjs/fluxible/fluxible-posts/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/statement.js:142:21)
    at Parser.parseStatement (/home/userOne/Development/reactjs/fluxible/fluxible-posts/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/flow.js:621:22)
    at Parser.pp.parseTopLevel (/home/userOne/Development/reactjs/fluxible/fluxible-posts/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/statement.js:30:21)
    at Parser.parse (/home/userOne/Development/reactjs/fluxible/fluxible-posts/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/index.js:70:17)
    at Object.parse (/home/userOne/Development/reactjs/fluxible/fluxible-posts/node_modules/babylon/lib/index.js:45:50)
```

Comment: Hello.  Yes, I have installed less-loader and css-loader.  I assume its just npm install less-loader and that's it right?  Do I need to require it?  Thank you

Comment: How do you import it in the code?

Comment: into my component?  `import('../assets/styles/main.less')` for example

Comment: The error message shows that you do `'./main.less'`. Could you also please since now show the **EXACT CODE** not made up syntactically incorrect examples (it's not helpful at all)?

Comment: Oh my.. I feel really stupid.  Thanks, I changed that part.  However, now it is saying `ERROR in Cannot find module 'less'
 @ ./components/Home.js 23:0-37`

Comment: sure.  please give me a min i will update the post above.  sorry.  i have updated the Home.js component code.

Comment: Well, it says you don't have a `less` module installed.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm really ashamed, I'm really sorry I've never done this before.  OK, I've installed the less module.  I ran npm run dev once again, and now I'm getting another error :(  Unexpected token

Comment: Yes, you're missing a space, I believe

Comment: Hi, now its throwing a new error.  Parser.pp.raise.  I've updated the main post

Comment: you'll probably want style loader to be in the loader chain as well

Comment: I've added that but the Parser.pp error is still there.